# Identifier 'isDesktopDevice' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to display a Sidebar component only if the user visits the app using a desktop device.

I Installed ngx-device-detector as per [ngx-device-detector documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector)

But I get the error: isDesktopDevice is not defined.

What am I missing?

My code below:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { User } from './_models/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  deviceInfo = null;
  jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService) {
    this.epicFunction();
  }

  epicFunction() {
    this.deviceInfo = this.deviceService.getDeviceInfo();
    const isMobile = this.deviceService.isMobile();
    const isTablet = this.deviceService.isTablet();
    const isDesktopDevice = this.deviceService.isDesktop();

    console.log(this.deviceInfo);
    console.log(isMobile);  // returns if the device is a mobile device (android / iPhone / windows-phone etc)
    console.log(isTablet);  // returns if the device us a tablet (iPad etc)
    console.log(isDesktopDevice); // returns if the app is running on a Desktop browser.
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    const toShow = this.deviceService.isDesktop();
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (token) {
      this.authService.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
    }
    if (user) {
      this.authService.currentUser = user;
      this.authService.changeMemberPhoto(user.photoUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

`<app-nav></app-nav>
<app-side-bar *ngIf="isDesktopDevice"></app-side-bar>`

Comment: Well, indeed, your component class doesn't have any **property** named isDesktopDevice. It only has a local variable named this way in epicFunction. Local variables are... local. They can't be used outside of the block where they're defined. Your component has two public properties: deviceInfo and jwtHelper